# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty}4 x \left(1 + \frac{\log\frac{1 + e^3}{1 + e^x}}{x}\right)$ in two ways gives different answers

Tags: limits

So
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}4 x \left(1 + \frac{\log\frac{1 + e^3}{1 + e^x}}{x}\right)$$
made a problem for me, which is: okay, first, the answer for this limit is $4\log(1+e^3)$, but I got $- 12$ somehow.

I used l'hopital's rule for $\log((1+e^3)/(1+e^x))/x$, where I got $1$, and I continue to get to $-12$.

But in another way, if you separated $\log(1+e^3)$ from $\log(1+e^x)$ you'll get the right answer, although I don't see where is the wrong. I mean, why if I didn't separate the $\log(1+e^3)$ will I get a wrong answer?

My idea is that we should leave the constants apart from the variables, you know, like when you solve an equation you take the constants on RHS and the variables on the LHS, So is it the same here?

From WolframAlpha:
[image: WolframAlpha's solution]

By the way, WolframAlpha didn't take the expression as it is, but its inverse. I don't know why, but it's the same principle.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is [a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: thanks it looks so much nicer, appreciate it. I'll try for the next time. Thanks again mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L'Hôpital's rule lets you write $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f}{g}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f^\prime}{g^\prime}$ (under the right conditions), but not$$\lim_{x\to\infty}4x\left(1+\frac{f}{g}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}4x\left(1+\frac{f^\prime}{g^\prime}\right).$$One correct approach notes$$\begin{align}4x\left(1+\frac{\ln(1+e^3)-\ln(1+e^x)}{x}\right)&=4x\frac{\ln(1+e^3)-\ln(1+e^{-x})}{x}\\&=4(\ln(1+e^3)-\ln(1+e^{-x})).\end{align}$$

Comment: but using the limit multiplication rule, i can separate 4x from f/g, then i'll apply independently l'hopital rule on f/g

Comment: @ElieMakdissi: You can only say that the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits if they both exist. You end up with a limit of $4x$ (which does not exist), and a limit of $\frac{4xf}{g}$, and using L’Hopital on that limit does not lead to just $f’/g’$, it leads to $(4f+4xf’)/g’$.

Comment: ah okayy great, i understand. thanks a lot m8